# pandas equivalent for excels 'file origin'

Tags: excel, pandas

Have csv files. When open in excel or pandas, foreign letters turns in gibberish.

In excel, I go to

Data --> From Text --> Specify File --> Step 1 and change 'File Origin' and it solved the problem.

How do I do this while importing file into dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain which characters turn into "gibberish". Show us an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the `encoding` parameter while reading the csv file as follows

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding="SHIFT-JIS")